# QGIS: check and repair geometry

Tags: qgis-3, geometry

I'm studying how to check and repair geometry correctly and found the "check geometry" tool which seems to work fine.

However there are also tools called "check validity" and "fix geometry" which seem to do the same. How do they work? Are they doing exactly the same as the "check geometry" tool? Is there a situation when one should use these two tools rather than "check geometry"?

After all, "check geometry" gives me a list of repair strategies to choose from, "fix geometry" just chooses a strategy to fix the geometry.

Comment: I always assumed the `Check geometry` tool was an advanced configuration of the `Check validity` and `Fix geometry` tools combined. Personally, I would use `Check geometry` for in-depth problems when dealing with geometries in tens of meters or less. The other two tools I would use for quick checks and fixes for testing or visualising purposes with larger, simpler geometries.